# Numpy: What is the most Pythonic way of taking a "rolling" matrix from array?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a `np.array` such as:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Given a window of size 5, I want to and get:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2, 3, 4, 5, 6
3, 4, 5, 6, 7
4, 5, 6, 7, 8
5, 6, 7, 8, 9
6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

It's an easy problem any rookie can solve, just wanted to know what is the most Pythonic numpy implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how badly you want to avoid copying that data. If badly enough, use [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
arr = np.arange(11)
window = 7
as_strided(arr, shape=(window, arr.size - window + 1), strides=arr.strides * 2, writeable=False)
```

This will make an array that has views of the same element in multiple places, so I've set `writable=False`. You can always make an expanded copy if you like.